# summation of two columns in Aggregate Method

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb Aggregate query. My db is like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a81636f017e441d609283cc"),
  "userid": "123",
  page : 'A',
  newpage: 'A',
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a81636f017e441d609283cd"),
  "userid": "123",
  page : 'B',
  newpage: 'A',
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a81636f017e441d609283ce"),
  "userid": "123",
  page : 'D',
  newpage: 'D',
}
```

I want to get the Sum of all page and new page value. I am able to get one column value which can give the very precise result.

But I am stuck with the two columns. What I did for getting the sum/repetition of values for one column is:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
                    {$match:{ "userid":"123"}},
                    {$unwind:"$newpage"},
                    {$group:{"_id":"$newpage", "count":{"$sum":1}}}, 
                    {$project: {_id:0, pagename :"$_id", count:{ $multiply: [ "$count", 1 ] }}},
                    {$sort: {count: -1}},
                    //{$limit: 10}              
               ], function(error, data){
                   if (error) {
                       console.log(error);
                   } else {
                    console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Desired Result will be like:

```
    {
        "pagename": "A",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "pagename": "D",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "pagename": "B",
        "count": 1
    }
```

Is anyone has any approach to getting these things for Two Column? Any Help is appreciated

Comment: What's your MongoDB Server version? If it is 3.4 or newer then [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) allows you to process multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents.

Comment: @chridam mine version is 3.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** pipeline stage to process multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. In your case you need to aggregate the counts separately then join the two results and calculate the final aggregates.

This can be demonstrated by running the following pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userid": "123" } },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "groupByPage": [
                { "$unwind": "$page" },
                { 
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$page",
                        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }
                }
            ],   
            "groupByNewPage": [
                { "$unwind": "$newpage" },
                { 
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$newpage",
                        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "pages": {
                "$concatArrays": ["$groupByPage", "$groupByNewPage"]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$pages" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$pages._id",
            "count": { "$sum": "$pages.count" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }
], function(error, data){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

Comment: Two issues here: a) The first `$unwind` stages are not needed. b) The `$setUnion` will remove duplicates which you don't want.

Comment: If you look closely at the OP's current working pipeline, there is an `$unwind` stage which shows the original document has `newpage` or `page` as arrays otherwise the pipeline would have thrown an error. You are correct about the `$setUnion` though, edited.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{ "userid":"123"}}, // filter out what's not of interest
    {$facet: { // process two stages in parallel --> this will give us a single result document with the following two fields
        "newpage": [ // "newpage" holding the ids and sums per "newpage" field
            {$group:{"_id":"$newpage", "count":{"$sum":1}}}
        ],
        "page": [ // and "page" holding the ids and sums per "page" field
            {$group:{"_id":"$page", "count":{"$sum":1}}}
        ]
    }},
    {$project: {x:{$concatArrays:["$newpage", "$page"]}}}, // merge the two arrays into one
    {$unwind: "$x"}, // flatten the single result document into multiple ones so we do not need to $reduce but can nicely $group
    {$group: {_id: "$x._id", "count": {$sum: "$x.count"}}} // perform the final grouping/counting,
    {$sort: {count: -1}} // well, the sort according to your question
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach. Really appreciate